# ssd how full is too full, performance slowdown or other negative effects

Tags: ssd

so ive read that its not good to fill up a ssd. im wondering how full is too full?

i have around 100 gigs of data and i am looking to get a 128gb ssd, is that too small? or will i be okay as long as i dont get too close to full capacity?

i dont plan on adding large amounts of data, mostly word documents and other realtively small files.

please let me know if i am getting too close and will experience any bad effects

my budget is good for a 128gb drive but ifi have to i can find some extra cash for a bigger drive.

Answer (score 1):

In general, writing to and deleting from an SSD is what makes it "age", not the fill status.
So if you plan to fill it once with the 100GiB and then only produce minor write activity, everything should be fine.

The general opinion is, however, that SSDs should only be filled up to 80-85%, so the drive can do its reallocation when individual chips fail.

Some even recommend leaving 10-15% unformatted, to have additional unused chips, but in general all SSDs have 10% reserve capacity, that is not allocatable by the user at all.

To sum this up: A 128GB disk should be sufficient for your needs.